# CSS Grid - grid-gap causes container to become too small

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm rather new at CSS-Grid and don't compeltely understand everything. But as soon as I set a grid-gap, the container-element, seems to be to small to contain all the elements. Everything looks as expected, but if I inspect the container I can see that it is too narrow. What did I do wrong?

Here is a fiddle where you can see the problem.
The blue background-part should not have a few pixels missing on the right.

```
article {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;;
  grid-template-rows: 280px auto;
  grid-gap: 6px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  height: 424px;
  width: 560px;
}

article > div {
  background-color: #f1a76c;
}

article > div.large{ 
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 3;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 2;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/juqqernaut/56tz9cv3/10/

Thank you for your help

Comment: column at 50% + gap is greater than 100% ;) . use 1fr intead: https://jsfiddle.net/56tz9cv3/14/

Comment: Ah that's right, "fr" is used for fractions of the whole grid, right? Thank you for you quick and competent answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr)` for `article` element.

Updated - https://jsfiddle.net/56tz9cv3/17/

Comment: Please add code to the answer. If jsfiddles quits the answer might not be clear enough for future visitors. SO also provides functionality to add a snippet